# Regex: Find word that does not have a different target anywhere ahead of it in the file?

Tags: regex, ansible

How do I find a word that does not have a specific target text anywhere ahead of it in a file?

Let's say I want to find "setting3" **not** preceeded by a right square bracket "]" (which denotes a header). This following file would fail that test, due to [header]:

```
[header] #can be named anything
setting1=True
setting2=various setting values, can include any type of text
setting3=1
```

But a file with an orphaned setting should be a match:

```
setting3=1
```

Lookbehinds won’t work, because I may have arbitrary settings in between the header and the text I'm looking for. Because my terms span multiple lines, it makes it trickier.

For context, this is to set a rule with a tool that only offers one regex line (Ansible, which I think uses Python's regex engine). I don't believe I have access to special settings (global, etc.)

Comment: If square brackets can only appear in headers, you can search for `^[^[]*setting3=1` or something similar. https://regex101.com/r/OHwLXp/2 ; you will want to put the searched string and/or what precedes it in capturing groups to manipulate them, unless ansible's engine supports variable-width lookbehinds (edit: it doesn't)

Comment: You're using [`replace`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/replace_module.html)? In this case the solution outlined above won't work as `replace` seems to force the use of the MULTILINE flag, the absence of which my solution relies on. You could try `(?-m)^[^[]*setting3=1` (see https://regex101.com/r/OHwLXp/4)

Comment: I'm trying to fix the "Ensure gpgcheck Enabled For All yum Package Repositories" rule from [here](https://github.com/RedHatOfficial/ansible-rhel7-nist-800-171-cui-role/blob/master/tasks/main.yml). That rule inserts a "gpgcheck=1" into a file without checking if there is a section that requires it. My fix would be to add an additional rule that finds these orphans and adds some nullifying text using blockinfile.

Comment: @Aaron, that first ^[^[]*setting3=1 expression worked! Pop it in an answer and I'll give you your checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use the following regular expression :

```
^[^[]*setting3=1
```

It matches from the start of the file up to the setting you're looking for, but only matching characters that aren't `[`, which guarantees that it will only match the setting you're looking for if it wasn't preceded by an header since they contain `[`.

Note that this could miss some settings that should be matched, in particular if comments preceding the setting contain a `[` character.

Comment: Thanks, the beginning ^ was the important part I was missing in my previous attempts!